# Regex matching newlines when it shouldn't?

Tags: regex

I don't understand. In .NET i specify RegexOptions.Multiline, using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ i checkoff global and multiline

What I expect is `^` and `$` to match the start and end of the line and `.` to match anything but a newline. What's happening is `.*` appears to match newline which seems wrong since msdn says `Single` flag allows it to match newline (which I am not using). I am using Linq to convert group 1 as key and 2 as value and all values work except the first. I guess I can do something with substring but why does flash and .NET say this pattern matches and how do I fixes (I guess i can use substring if i need to)

Pattern:

```
^\s*([^\:]+)\s*\:\s*(.*)$
```

Input

```
ffmp


eg version N-54691-g7f4a1fd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 12 2013 16:26:02 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 39.100 / 52. 39.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 80.101 /  3. 80.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, ogg, from 'd:\music\a.ogg':
  Duration: 00:03:24.49, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 195 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
----
---
      ARTIST          : Anamanaguchi
      TITLE           : Blackout City
      ALBUM ARTIST    : Anamanaguchi
      ALBUM           : Dawn Metropolis
      track           : 1
      YEAR            : 2009
      GENRE           : rock
      DATE            : 2009
      ENCODER         : MediaMonkey 4.0.3
      ENSEMBLE        : Anamanaguchi
      RATING          : -1
At least one output file must be specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this pattern instead:

```
^\s*([^:\n]+)\s*:\s*(.*)$
```

It is because of your character class `[^:]` which matches all characters except `:` but including newlines.

Keep in mind, that *single line mode* means only that the dot can match newlines. Since you use a character class, you have the same behaviour with or without the mode

Comment: Right but not 100% correct. It appears `\s*` matches new lines as well so I replaced `\s*` with ` *` and problem solved